# Schedule an Automation through the API without a Recurrence("Repeat") Value

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, automationstudio, automation, schedule

Is this possible to do? Each time I schedule an automation through the API it only seems to work if I set a "Recurrence" value, although I only want the automation to run once.

To get around this I've been setting the Recurrence to an arbitrary 5000 days while also setting the "Occurrences" to 1 so that the automation ends after it is run(example below). This has been working fine but I'd like to avoid doing it if possible.

[image]

Comment: are you looking to have it do a 'run once' where it runs immediately or do you want to schedule it for a future date and have it only run that one time?

Comment: Schedule it for a future date and have it only run one time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To set this, you need to have a recurrence set, but you can set this to 1, which is exactly what is set inside the UI version.

Example SOAP:

```
  <ScheduleRequestMsg xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
     <Action>start</Action>
     <Schedule>
        <!-- Can leave blank to use current schedule -->
        <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true"/>
        <ObjectID xsi:nil="true"/>
        <Recurrence xsi:type="q1:DailyRecurrence" xmlns:q1="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
            <q1:DailyRecurrencePatternType>Interval</q1:DailyRecurrencePatternType>
            <q1:DayInterval>1</q1:DayInterval>
        </Recurrence>
        <RecurrenceType>Daily</RecurrenceType>
        <RecurrenceRangeType>EndAfter</RecurrenceRangeType>
        <StartDateTime>2030-05-16T14:32:00-04:00</StartDateTime>
        <Occurrences>1</Occurrences>
     </Schedule>
     <Interactions>
        <Interaction xsi:type="Automation">
           <ObjectID>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</ObjectID>
        </Interaction>
     </Interactions>
  </ScheduleRequestMsg>
```

Screen shot from UI setting:
[image]

ScreenShot of schedule via API:
[image]

As you can see there is no difference between the SOAP setting and the UI setting.

The REST Endpoint that @RachidMamai spoke of is great, but it has no way to actually set the Automation to 'active'. Which would require extra action.

Comment: A thousand thank yous to you Gortonington. This works perfectly, you're the best!

Comment: This works for me. How do you specify usage of your local preferred Time Zone? Based on the lookup table for SFMC time zones, Using SOAP I tried adding TimezoneID int value from the table (i.e. 76 for 'Eastern Time'). However, it doesn't change it from it's default of 'Central Time'. 
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/timezone.htm

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this via the REST API using the undocumented endpoint `/automation/v1/automations/{{automation_object_id}}`.

Do a PATCH request to:

```
YOUR_DOMAIN/automation/v1/automations/YOUR_AUTOMATION_OBJECT_ID
```

The request's JSON payload is similar to:

```
{
  "name": "AUTOMATION_NAME",
  "description": "DESC",
  "key": "YOUR_AUTOMATION_KEY",
  "steps": [],
  "startSource": {
    "typeId": 1,
    "schedule": {
      "iCalRecur": "FREQ=HOURLY;INTERVAL=1;COUNT=1",
      "startDate": "2019-12-06T14:00:00",
      "timeZoneId": 7
    }
  },
  "categoryId": 486
}
```

Of course, you can change the `FREQ` to `DAILY`, `WEEKLY`,..

Using this payload, your automation will only be scheduled to run once.

Comment: I think this will set it in a 'paused' state though. The schedule will be there, but not activated yet

Comment: Correct, I've tried multiple payloads and even forced the ScheduleStatus to "active" without sucess. There is no way of achieving this via REST API at the moment. Automation Studio is using a REST call to a beta endpoint that is not accessible from outside SFMC..

Comment: Yeah, this is a pain point that I have been pushing on SFMC, especially around a Triggered File Drop automation as there is not a SOAP nor a REST solution (outside internal endpoints) to activate it/pause it.